# Calculate $\int_{0}^{\frac{b}{a}}\frac{e^{\frac{x}{ax-b}}}{x+1}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

My high school classmate encountered a problem while doing a physics experiment and needed to find the answer of the integral shown below:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{b}{a}}\frac{b}{(b-ax)^2}·e^{\frac{x}{ax-b}}·\log_2(1+x)\mathrm{d}x \tag{1}$$
where $a$ and $b$ is positive real number.
He asked me for help, and I turned it to this form:
$$\frac{1}{\ln2}\int_{0}^{\frac{b}{a}}\frac{e^{\frac{x}{ax-b}}}{x+1}\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}$$
However, the original function of this integral is not elementary function. I don't know how to solve it.
I tried assigning values to $a$ and $b$, and put it on Wolfram Alpha, it returns me the answer in the form of: $$\frac{1}{\ln 2}\left[\sqrt[a]{e}\operatorname{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)-\sqrt[a+b]{e}\operatorname{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{a+b}\right)\right] \tag{3}$$
I just wonder how integral $(2)$ can be transformed to integral $(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$\frac{x}{a x-b}=-t \quad \implies \quad x=\frac{b t}{a t+1}\quad \implies \quad dx=\frac{b}{(a t+1)^2}\,dt$$
$$I=\int\frac{b e^{-t}}{(a t+1) (t (a+b)+1)}\,dt$$ Partial fraction decompsition
$$\frac{1}{(a t+1) (t (a+b)+1)}=\frac{a+b}{b (t (a+b)+1)}-\frac{a}{b (a t+1)}$$ that you can write
$$\frac 1{b\left(t+\frac 1{a+b} \right)}-\frac 1{b\left(t+\frac 1{a} \right)}$$
$$I=\int \frac{ e^{-t}} {\left(t+\frac 1{a+b} \right)}\,dt-\int \frac{ e^{-t}} {\left(t+\frac 1{a} \right)}\,dt$$
Now, two obvious changes of variables

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!